# WooCommerce - checkout - check for minimum amount or cart total?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

Customer want end users to buy at least *X*€ **or** *y* items, so i need to check this before user actually pay.

I know i need to disable/remove cart "Proceed to checkout" and checkout "Place order" buttons, but to be really sure i'd like to tap into a non-ui hook (if any exists) that is being called upon making the purchase and add needed checks.

I cannot find anything on woocommerce docs, any advise?

Comment: The correct hook to be used is [`woocommerce_check_cart_items`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=[woocommerce]%20woocommerce_check_cart_items&searchOn=3) and here are [some useful answers I made with `woocommerce_check_cart_items` hook](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=user%3a3730754%20woocommerce_check_cart_items&searchOn=3)... This will be a good start to code yourself something convenient.

Answer (score 0):

```
function custom_minimum_order_amount() {
    $minimum_amount = 100; // Set the minimum order amount
    $minimum_quantity = 3; // Set the minimum item quantity

    // Get the cart total and item count
    $cart_total = WC()->cart->get_cart_total();
    $cart_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();

    // Perform the minimum order amount check
    if ($cart_total < $minimum_amount) {
        wc_add_notice(sprintf('Minimum order amount is %s. Please add more items to your cart.', wc_price($minimum_amount)), 'error');
    }

    // Perform the minimum item quantity check
    if ($cart_count < $minimum_quantity) {
        wc_add_notice(sprintf('Minimum item quantity is %s. Please add more items to your cart.', $minimum_quantity), 'error');
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'custom_minimum_order_amount');
```